# Unwanted punctuation in cleveref rererences

Tags: cross-referencing, counters, cleveref, tasks

I use `cleveref` for referencing. There are a set of questions (which could be items) and their subquestions, which I want to come out as "question 1.1" or (preferably) "subquestion 2.3" when referring to their labels.

However I see no way to name the counters associated with `tasks` within `\crefname`. I can live with it, if only the punctuation of the subquestion do not get in the way.

This is my MWE and a picture to explain it all.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tasks,cleveref,xsim}

\crefname{exercise}{question}{questions}

% what should be the correct counter here, nothing seems to work
\crefname{tsk}{subquestion}{subquestions}
\crefname{subquestion}{subquestion}{subquestions}
\crefname{subquestionn}{subquestion}{subquestions}
\crefname{tsk[1]}{subquestion}{subquestions}

% type of subquestions
\NewTasks[counter-format = tsk[1]),label-format = \itshape]{parts}[\subquestion](2)
\NewTasks[counter-format = (tsk[1]*,label-format = \itshape]{follow}[\subquestionn](2)

% a hack just to get subquestion referencing
\newcommand{\refsubq}[1]{\cref{#1}.\ref{#1}}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{exercise}
        what is the name of the game? \label{game}
        \begin{parts}
            \subquestion who plays the game? \label{game1}
            \subquestion do they all lose? \label{game2}
        \end{parts}
    \end{exercise}
    
    \begin{exercise}
        what is the game? \label{name}
        \begin{follow}
            \subquestionn is it real? \label{name1}
            \subquestionn have you played it? \label{name2}
        \end{follow}
    \end{exercise}
    
    \section*{References}
    
    \noindent Refer exercise basic = \ref{name}
    
    \noindent Refer exercise cleverref = \cref{game}
    
    \noindent Refer subquestion basic = \ref{game1}
    
    \noindent Refer subquestion cleverref = \cref{game1} % ideally I want it to output "subquestion 1.1"
    
    \noindent Refer subquestion refsubq = \refsubq{name2}
    
\end{document}
```

My query is

1. How do I get `\cref` to print "subquestion" while refering to subquestions and "question" while refering to questions? In effect, I want to get rid of `\refsubq`.
2. How do I get rid of the `counter-format` punctuations while print the output of `\cref`. the MWE and picture explains it well?

It is a not an issue with `xsim`-package. I see the same behavior with `\item` within `\item`.

[image]

Comment: How do you compile your MWE? I get loads of warnings

Comment: I see no major warnings.  only two bad-boxes. i am using texlive-2017. perhaps commenting out the ineffective ``\crefname`` directives would get rid of warnings

Answer (score 1):

You just need

- an up to date `tasks` (from 2020/05/11),
- tell `cleveref` to use the counter `task` and
- set the `ref` option accordingly when you define a new `tasks` environment:

Here is an adaption of your MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tasks,cleveref,xsim}

\crefname{exercise}{question}{questions}
\crefname{task}{subquestion}{subquestions}

% type of subquestions
\newcommand*\Star{*}
\NewTasksEnvironment[
  label = \arabic*),
  ref = \theexercise.\arabic*) ,
  label-format = \itshape ,
  label-width = 15pt
  ]{parts}[\subquestion](2)
\NewTasksEnvironment[
  label = (\arabic*\Star,
  ref = \theexercise.(\arabic*\Star ,
  label-format = \itshape,
  label-width = 15pt
]{follow}[\subquestionn](2)


\begin{document}

\begin{exercise}
  what is the name of the game? \label{game}
  \begin{parts}
    \subquestion who plays the game? \label{game1}
    \subquestion do they all lose? \label{game2}
   \end{parts}
\end{exercise}

\begin{exercise}
  what is the game? \label{name}
  \begin{follow}
    \subquestionn is it real? \label{name1}
    \subquestionn have you played it? \label{name2}
  \end{follow}
\end{exercise}

\section*{References}
Refer exercise cleverref = \cref{game} \\
Refer subquestion cleverref = \cref{game1} \\
Refer subquestion cleverref = \cref{game2}

Refer exercise cleverref = \cref{name} \\
Refer subquestion cleverref = \cref{name1} \\
Refer subquestion cleverref = \cref{name2}

\end{document}
```

[image]